# Random number having 11 to 20 digits

Tags: python, random

How to generate random numbers in python having(11 to 20 digits) that should not start with 0 in beginning?

e.g:23418915901

```
def key_more_than_10():
    v=random.randint(11,20)
    char_set = string.digits+string.digits+string.digits
    s= ''.join(random.sample(char_set,v))
    return s
```

I used this code but since string.digits(give numbers between 0 to 9) it doesnt help me?

There should be an equal possibility to have 11 digits number and a 20 digits number.

Comment: Hmmm, perhaps I'm missing something, but don't you want random.randint(10000000000, 99999999999999999999)?

Comment: A minor ambiguity in your question: obviously if you choose a random number between 11 and 20 digits it will usually have 20 digits, since there are many more 20 digit numbers than 11 digit. If you wanted the number of digits to be distributed uniformly, you could first choose it and then choose the number.

Answer (score 4):

Simple:

```
>>> help(random.randint)
Help on method randint in module random:

randint(self, a, b) method of random.Random instance
    Return random integer in range [a, b], including both end points.

>>> random.randint(10000000000,99999999999999999999)
35677750742418249489
```

Of course, if you actually want a string (not sure why you would), you could wrap a `str()` around the whole thing:

```
>>> str(random.randint(1000000000,99999999999999999999))
'91138793919270489115'
```

Comment: Will it always generate 20 digits numbers or it it will vary. Because when i checked it was giving most of the times 20 digit numbers. As i need it to change also (11 to 20)

Comment: @rohithbalasankaran - it will vary, but it is obvious, that most of the numbers have 20 digits. There are more than nine times so many 20-digit numbers as there are 11 to 19-digit numbers combined.

Comment: ok thanks alot. Just beginner to python thats why .Appreciate you guys help.......

Answer (score 2):

How about a literal translation of what you want into code:

```
import random
DIGITS = '0123456789'

ndigits = random.randint(11, 20)
digits = [random.choice(DIGITS[1:])] + [random.choice(DIGITS) for i in xrange(ndigits-1)]
print int(''.join(digits))
```

The number of digits in the *almost* random result should be uniformly distributed between 11..20. Not quite random because restricting the first digit to a something other than a zero precludes it.

Answer (score 1):

I would choose randrange for this

```
    Help on method randrange in module random:

    randrange(self, start, stop=None, step=1, int=<type 'int'>, default=None, maxwidth=9007199254740992L) method of random.Random instance
        Choose a random item from range(start, stop[, step]).

    This fixes the problem with randint() which includes the
    endpoint; in Python this is usually not what you want.
    Do not supply the 'int', 'default', and 'maxwidth' arguments.
```

so

```
random.randrange(1e11, 1e20)
```

will do what you want. For a string use this

```
str(random.randrange(1e11, 1e20))
```